# Export / import NSKeyedArchiver object file

Tags: swift3, nskeyedarchiver, nskeyedunarchiver

I save data using NSKeyedArchive, and pull with NSKeyedArchiver.

```
// file path
static var filePath : String{
    let url = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first
    return url!.appendingPathComponent("Data").path
}

// save locally
static func saveData(reviewDaysArray : [MyObjects]){
       NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(reviewDaysArray, toFile: filePath)
}

// get local data 
static func getData() -> [MyObjects]{
    if let data = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(withFile: filePath) as? [MyObjects]{
        return data
    }

    return [MyObjects]()
}
```

Is it possible for the user to export NSKeyedArchiver object and then restore if necessary?

Answer (score 0):

you can simply export your data to Data (a.k.a NSData) see the docs at https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nskeyedunarchiver

And then you can do with it anything you want, like mail attachment (see MFMailComposeViewController)